# Failed to inject EJB 3 using @EJB on jboss 7

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss7.x

```
I am trying to use @EJB annotation to call a stateless bean. When I print the value of the reference, it is NULL I a'm running on jboss 7. Please help me I have traied all possipole configruation, If I missed any thing please notify me. find the full stack below
```

Jboss log:-

JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "medmark.war"
    17:33:56,948 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-8) JNDI bindings for session bean named HelloService in deployment unit deployment "medmark.war" are as follows:

```
    java:global/medmark/HelloService!com.ntgclarity.medmark.service.HelloService
    java:app/medmark/HelloService!com.ntgclarity.medmark.service.HelloService
    java:module/HelloService!com.ntgclarity.medmark.service.HelloService
    java:global/medmark/HelloService
    java:app/medmark/HelloService
    java:module/HelloService

17:33:57,374 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
17:33:57,388 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
17:33:57,580 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-6) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7-jbossorg-1 (20120227-1401) for context '/medmark'
17:33:58,651 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-6) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
17:33:59,582 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (MSC service thread 1-6) Running on PrimeFaces 5.0
17:33:59,627 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /medmark
17:33:59,644 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
17:33:59,652 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 8464ms - Started 349 of 476 services (126 services are passive or on-demand)
17:33:59,953 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "medmark.war"
17:34:01,423 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error Rendering View[/portal/login.xhtml]: com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Cant instantiate class: com.ntgclarity.medmark.managedbean.HelloBean.
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:193) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:75) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:67)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:48)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ntgclarity.medmark.managedbean.HelloBean.<init>(HelloBean.java:59) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    ... 42 more

17:34:01,781 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/medmark].[facesServlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet facesServlet threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ntgclarity.medmark.managedbean.HelloBean.<init>(HelloBean.java:59) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:147) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:169) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.getValueToRender(ComponentUtils.java:75) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeMarkup(InputTextRenderer.java:71) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at org.primefaces.component.inputtext.InputTextRenderer.encodeEnd(InputTextRenderer.java:52) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.1.Final.jar:2.0.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.event(JBossWebContext.java:67)
    at org.jboss.modcluster.container.jbossweb.JBossWebContext$RequestListenerValve.invoke(JBossWebContext.java:48)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]

pom.xml
<properties>
        <!-- API Versions -->
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <!-- Settings -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <org.springframework-version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.spring.security-version>3.1.4.RELEASE</org.spring.security-version>
        <com.sun.faces>2.2.4</com.sun.faces>
        <primefaces.version>5.0</primefaces.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!--PRIMEFACES REPOSITORY -->
        <repository>
            <id>prime-repo</id>
            <name>Prime Repo</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL CONNECTOR -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.31</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAVA SERVER FACES JSF API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${com.sun.faces}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAVA SERVER FACES JSF Imp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${com.sun.faces}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAVA JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAVA SERVLET -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PRIMEFACES 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>${primefaces.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>medmark</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
```

EJB class:

```
    @Stateless
    public class HelloService{

        public HelloService(){

        }
        public String sayHello() {
            return "Hello EJB";
        }
    }
```

JSF bean:

```
    @ManagedBean
    @RequestScoped
    public class HelloBean {

        @EJB
        HelloService service;

        private String testString;

        public HelloBean(){
            testString = service.sayHello();
        }
        public String getTestString() {
            return testString;
        }

        public void setTestString(String testString) {
            this.testString = testString;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it: you are using an injected bean in the -constructor-. But the constructor is the very first thing that is ever going to be invoked so of course nothing is injected yet at that point.

Rather do it in a post construct method.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class HelloBean {

    @EJB
    HelloServiceLocal service;

    private String testString;

    public HelloBean(){
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
      testString = service.sayHello();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Gimby, I have tried to use @PostConstruct but nothing changes ?!! dose I have to implement local interface ?

Comment: Since JEE6 it is not necessary anymore. Sorry, I can't know what else you might be missing with what you've provided.

Comment: @IbrahimQandeel What was the reason why you still had problems?

Comment: I've used

@EJB
HelloServiceLocal service;
 
instead of
HelloService service;

and clean and build the project

Comment: Ah okay yes. IF you give your bean a local interface then you have to use it. But since JEE6 you are not forced to give it any kind of interface anymore.